# Why is my geometry shader becoming "overloaded"?

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I use an OpenGL shader to plot graphs.  Every span of the graph has the form:

[image]

The vertex shader just passes the a's and b's to a geometry shader that then evaluates the curve at `max_vertices` points.

The problem is that sometimes the geometry shader seems to become "overloaded" and stops spitting out points:

[image]

Both curves actually have the exact same values, but for some reason the bottom one has some kind of failure of the geometry shader to generate points.

When I change `max_vertices` in the following line of my geometry shader:

```
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = ${max_vertices}) out;
```

from 1024 (the result of `gl.glGetInteger(gl.GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES)`) to 256, then I get the desired output:

[image]

What is happening?  What is the true maximum number of vertices?  Why is the top graph unaffected, but the bottom one corrupted?  They have the same data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometry shaders have [two competing sets of limitations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Output_limitations). The first is the number of vertices in each GS invocation, and the second is the total number of components you output from a GS invocation (retrieved from `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`). You must stay within both to get defined behavior.

1024 is the required minimum value for `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`; all implementations will support at least that many. If an implementation only supports that number, and you tried to output 1024 vertices, you could only output a single component of data for each such vertex (a single `float` or `int` or whatever, not even a `vec2`).

Overall, it would be better to avoid this problem entirely. What you're trying to do seems like it'd be more easily done via a [compute shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader) or at the very least, [geometry shader instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Instancing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Would you mind going into more details about what using a compute shader or geometry shader instancing involves, and why it is better than my solution?

Comment: I have added the following line, which fixes my problem: `max_vertices = min(max_vertices, max_total_components // 4)` so thanks again.